# Unable to Json Serialize Twilio MessageResource object returned from MessageResource.CreateAsync

Tags: c#, json.net, twilio

I have this C# twilio code to send a SMS to the Twilio api

```
var msg = MessageResource.CreateAsync(
                    pathAccountSid: _subAccountSid,
                    body: messageBody,
                    messagingServiceSid: messagingServiceId,
                    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    ).Result;
```

I then want to serialize msg, like this

```
try
{
    var k1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var kilroy = ex;
}
```

This is not working.
The exception is a System.ArgumentNullException.
with a value of "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'o')"

also tried this

```
try
{
    var jsonSerializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    var writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
    jsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, msg);
    var k2 = sw.ToString();
    writer.Close();
    sw.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var kilroy = ex;
}
```

results in same exception.

The stack looks like this:

> ```
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(Object value, String parameterName)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObjectInternal(Object o, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(Object o)
> at Twilio.Converters.PhoneNumberConverter.WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable(JsonWriter writer, JsonConverter converter, Object value, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)
> at SmsApi.Services.TwilioService.SendMessage(String messagingServiceId, String messageBody, String[] recipients) 
> in TwilioService.cs:line 153
> ```

The twilio method CreateAsync() is found in the Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account namespace.

fwiw,
I've been able to do something similar in a different method without exception:

```
var newService = ServiceResource.Create(new CreateServiceOptions(friendlyName));
return new ServiceResourceDto()
{
    Name = newService.FriendlyName,
    Sid = newService.Sid,
    AllJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newService),
    DateCreated = newService.DateCreated,
    DateUpdated = newService.DateUpdated
};
```

Comment: Please post the values of `pathAccountSid` and the other properties. One might be null?

Comment: @Train these values contain sensitive info

Comment: We can't tell unless we see if `CreateAsync` is being executed successful. Can you show us some example info that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var msg = MessageResource.CreateAsync(
                    pathAccountSid: _subAccountSid,
                    body: messageBody,
                    messagingServiceSid: messagingServiceId,
                    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    ).Result;
```

in my case does return a valid msg.

I serialize the result this way and it is now working:

```
                var dto = new MessageResourceDto()
                {
                    Sid = msg.Sid,
                    DateCreated = msg.DateCreated,
                    DateUpdated = msg.DateUpdated,
                    AllJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<MessageResource>(msg)
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the basics you need. If your `MessageResource` does not get created successfuly, your Result / Task will be null as well.

Minimum code I used to test the CreateAsync call is below.. tested successfully,

```
string yourAccountSid = "YourAccountSID";
string yourAuthToken = "YourAuthToken";

TwilioClient.Init(yourAccountSid, yourAuthToken);
var msg = MessageResource.CreateAsync(
        pathAccountSid: yourAccountSid,
        body: "MessageBody",
        from: new PhoneNumber("YourTwilioPhoneNumber"),
        to: new PhoneNumber("ValidPhoneNumber")
        ).Result;

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg));
```

Comment: Thanks Jawad, The SerializeObject(msg) works for you?  In my case I'm using a different MessageResource.CreateAsync() which does return a valid result, but the serialize fails. I did resolve it a different way which I post next.

Comment: Yes.. because the Task was successfully created /executed. Validate the data you have for each of your variables and try again.